# How to perform a operation after partial page loading completed in AngularJS.

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We are listing the list of scope datas(page1) in one page. in that page have  buttons edit & cancel, while page loading those two buttons are disabled using html attribute (disabled="disabled"). 
     when ever the user click on the edit button in toolbar list that time buttons want to enabled(it's working fine). Then user will click any one scope data for edit. it will redirect to Page2
     After edit we are updating that data  to localstorage/server , once user will click update/save then it will redirect to partial page where we are listing the all the scope datas(page1). 
     that time buttons are showing disabled but i want to be enabled. Once the edit operation done after buttons are always in enabled only. Please help me how to achive this in AngularJS.

Source Code:

```
// Saving data in Local scope
     $scope.savingObjectAttribute = function(objectName) {      
            //Getting the all the values from the controls
            var fieldName = $("input#fieldName").val();
            var labelName =  $("input#labelName").val();
            //var controlType = $("#controltype").data("kendoDropDownList").text();            
            var dataTypename = $("#datatype").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
            var dataTypeId = $("#datatype").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
            //inserting all the field values into rowset array
            if(fieldName!="" && $scope.state=="new") {
                //Pushing the Attributes information to array
                $scope.attributes.push({AttributeName: fieldName, LabelName: labelName, DataTypeName: dataTypename,  DataTypeId: dataTypeId });

                //Storing the attributes collections to browser localStorage                
                $scope.attributesSavingToLocal($scope.attributes);

                $scope.objectName=objectName;
                //Clearing the existing html elements   
                clearPartialElement();

                //Calling the angular services for partial page.
                $scope.customAttributeDetailsPage();            

            } else if(fieldName!="" && $scope.state=="edit") {  

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.attributes.length; i++) {
                       if($scope.attributes[i].AttributeName === fieldName){  
                           $scope.attributes[i].AttributeName = fieldName;
                           $scope.attributes[i].LabelName = labelName; 
                           $scope.attributes[i].DataTypeName = dataTypename; 
                           $scope.attributes[i].DataTypeId = dataTypeId; 
                           break; 
                       }
                }

                //Storing the attributes collections information to browser localStorage                
                $scope.attributesSavingToLocal($scope.attributes);

                $scope.objectName=objectName;
                //Clearing the existing html elements
                clearPartialElement();

                //Calling the angular services for partial page.
                $scope.customAttributeDetailsPage();

            } else  {
                $("input#fieldName").addClass('validation-error');
                $("input#labelName").addClass('validation-error');
                alert("Field and Label names are required!");
            }           

    };

    //Tool bar edit ( Its working when ever cliking)
    $toolbar.onEdit = function() {  
            //enabling the buttons in attributes page
            $('.btn-enable').removeAttr("disabled",'false').removeClass("k-state-disabled");        
    };

    // Actually i need to do above functionality after this partial page loaded in angularJS
    //Attribute Details Partial Page
    $scope.customAttributeDetailsPage = function() {
        //Calling the angular services for partial page.
        $http({
            url : './resources/staticPages/custom-object-attributes.html',
            method : "GET"
        }).success(function(data, status) {         
                $scope.data = data;             
                jQuery("objectViewPartial").html($compile($scope.data)($scope));
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                console.log("some error occured partial page");
        });     

    };
```

Comment: it's not really clear here what your question is, but this code looks like a mix of angular, JQuery, and kendo all mashed into one function.  There is no way Angular can accurately keep the page state in sync with code like this.  Why would you use angular `$http` to fetch a .html page and use JQuery to inject that HTML page into some random div?

Comment: What you are asking is trivial if you use angular properly and use services to share data across the app.  You are writing this as a jQuery app , not an angular app and need to start over using best practices. Your overall approach is completely wrong. An angular controller should never know about the DOM and it should never contain DOM code. Your data model should drive the view and let angular manage the DOM

Comment: The reason for mixing the angular and jQuery and kendo. we are already defined some of the component in javascript. now for partial pages only we are using the angular and accessing those components. for example  $toolbar. currently other functionalities working fine.

Comment: later we have to change  complete angular. Please advice how to solve this issue now.